# Insert row for X time

Tags: mysql, time, insert, row

I have a problem:

How I can insert a row and delete it X time?

I think something like `INSERT` the value whit a time stamp and add a task to delete it.

But I don't have idea how to add MySQL task and if here is a better method.

Comment: What do you mean? You insert one row, and delete it a number of times?!

Comment: I think he wants to add a temporary row and delete it after a certain amount of time. I'm not sure if you can do this with MySQL alone, but you could easily accomplish the same thing with PHP. Do you know PHP at all?

Comment: you mean? you need to schedule a task to insert and delete values periodically.

Comment: Exacly sakthi, im looking for that.
jerry, Php is only 1 way run, cant create task.
Gerald Versluis, I fail is "time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use event scheduler from MySQL:

the basic about MySQL scheduler is:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

Source:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Guide:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html